# Thread is not actually working

Tags: android

I'm a noobie in Java and Android I have a Thread question:
I have the following code that is triggered from android:onClick on the xml  layout
The resulting behavior is that the UI waits 5 seconds and only after those 5 seconds, the ProgressDialog starts.
Shouldn't the Thread start independently and the dialog pop immediately?
Why is the Thread stopping the course of the procedure?
Thanks!

```
// (Button)
public void buttonReadGps(View v){

    Thread readingGps = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            // Read GPS code will go here
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    readingGps.run();

    // Create a wait dialog
    prgDialg = new ProgressDialog(context);
    prgDialg.setTitle("Reading GPS...");
    prgDialg.setMessage("Please wait.");
    prgDialg.setCancelable(true);
    prgDialg.setIndeterminate(true);
    prgDialg.show();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
readingGps.run();
```

with

```
readingGps.start();
```

The problem is the first version will just run your method synchronously and block the main thread. The second version actually starts a thread and continues, so the method will run asynchronously on a new thread.

This is such a common pattern in Android that the SDK gives a few classes to help: be sure to check out [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and possibly [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html).

Comment: Details here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#start(). Try-catch the illegal state exception.